# Word for "of neutrinos"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word meaning of or related to neutrinos, in the way that "proton" has "protonic", "electron" has "electronic", etc.

Comment: "... dark matter includes baryonic (CDM) and neutrinoic (HDM) components." https://books.google.com/books?id=8g_yAAAAMAAJ "In the subatomic-nucleon template, this intersection corresponds to a precise formulation for the neutrinoic kernel of the Higgs Bosonic ..." http://www.cosmosdawn.net/forum/index.php?threads/the-legacy-of-thuban-omni-science-de-alpha-draconis-omega.2/page-2 "But the wavecentre of neutrinoic kernel forms the limit; ..." www.rbduncan.com/EB.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neutrinos are neutral, massless (or almost so) subatomic particles that as a result of these properties almost never interact with matter.  When scientists detected a supernova explosion in 1987, the physics calculations estimated that a billion trillion trillion trillion trillion neutrinos were released, of which the detectors picked up 19.

So it's not surprising that the neutrino has been rarely detected interacting with English usage.  The word "neutrinic" has shown up in papers, for example in [*Selected Papers on Gauge Theory of Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zMoLDTiM3aQC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=neutrinic&source=bl&ots=5jts4Slfav&sig=72Mb-CdhduzFV5_cew6tZA47wEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBWoVChMI58Gq4K3kxgIVxTaICh3avwqs#v=onepage&q=neutrinic&f=false) (1981)

> This invariance property implies a conservation law for a lepton field
>   quantity that we shall call **neutrinic** charge, n.

But this adjective hasn't caught on, and "neutrino" acts as its own adjective in compound noun constructions.  The google finds no instances of a "neutrinic detector," but over 96K references to a "neutrino detector."

Comment: Nice and balanced. And far from genref.

Comment: The *-ic* suffix in the sense of "related to"/ "of the nature of" is different from the adjectival usage in "neutrino detector." An *electron microscope* is not an *electronic microscope.*

Comment: @Kris This is an artifact of "electronic" having the meaning of a device controlling and controlled by electrical current.  This doesn't apply to other names of subatomic particles.  Thus we have ionic detectors, which are electronic devices that detect ions.  And protonic acids.

Comment: Kris seems to have found "neutrinoic" as another possible derived adjective; I don't know if you'd like to discuss that.

Comment: I expect it would have to be pronounced new-treen-OH-ic, to rhyme with heroic or stoic.  This puts it at adds with the other -ic forms of particles that don't end in a vowel, but I kinda like it.